# Not redirected to the default page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been using laravel default authentication system where it should redirect to the `dashboard` page when the user is successfully logged in and when the user is successfully registered. but in my case, when successfully registered it donot redirect to any page instead gives this error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

while my `routes.php` is:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

});
```

and `redirectusers.php`

```
 public function redirectPath()
    {


        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) 
{
            return $this->redirectPath;

     }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';

}

}
```

Comment: What is the code you have written in your controller for redirection?

Comment: Please show what does `AuthController.php` have in `protected $redirectTo =`. Also, you don't need to use `web` middleware as it is used automatically in 5.2.

Comment: in `redirectsusers.php` it is /home@DhavalBharadva

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin ok.updated the question.

Comment: @micky, I've asked about `AuthController.php`. Please look there for `protected $redirectTo =`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the redirectTo variable in the Auth controller

```
// AuthController.php

protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```